# Issue with Disqus comments

Tags: comments

I seem to be having a difficult time getting the [Disqus](https://drupal.org/project/disqus) module to work on my Drupal website. Installation is normal, I just can't get to Disqus configuration page. The configuration page is blank.

I want to know: Does Disqus have any tables? If it does: Can someone give me the table structure, to see if I can use it?

Comment: Cleared the cache? Or try uninstalling and re-installing to see if that fixes it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Disqus](https://drupal.org/project/disqus) module has it own table (named `disqus`).

To see this table, look up the file `disqus.install` and examine the array called [`$schema`](http://drupalcode.org/project/disqus.git/blob/ab99e69:/disqus.install).

You'll find this file inside the project directory (normally `sites/all/modules/disqus/`) where you installed Disqus, or in the project's [git repo](http://drupalcode.org/project/disqus.git/blob/ab99e69:/disqus.install) at *drupalcode.org*.

The Disqus schema is reproduced below for easy reference:

```
$schema['disqus'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'did' => array(
      'type' => 'serial',
      'not null' => TRUE,
     ),
     'nid' => array(
       'type' => 'int',
       'not null' => TRUE,
       'default' => 0,
     ),
     'status' => array(
       'type' => 'int',
       'unsigned' => TRUE,
       'size' => 'tiny',
       'not null' => TRUE,
       'default' => 0,
     ),
  ),
  'primary key' => array('did'),
  'indexes' => array(
    'nid' => array('nid'),
    'status' => array('status'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I am so sorry for the late reply. Currently online I have Drupal 7.26 and the disqus module does not seem to work. And yet on offline I have Drupal 7.22 and disqus works well.